# Optimal way to filter table rows based on a variable JSON array in SQL using JOIN or other methods?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, open-json

I have a table A with a large number of rows and an id column. Additionally, I have a variable @Json that can have three types of values: null, an empty array '[]', or a JSON array like '[1,2,3]'. I am looking for the optimal way to filter the rows of table A based on the value of the @Json variable.

If @Json is null, I want to retrieve all rows from table A. If @Json is an empty array '[]', I don't want to retrieve any rows from table A. If @Json contains a JSON array, I want to retrieve only the rows where the id column value exists in that array.

Example:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

Cases:

`@Json NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;` - Should fetch all rows

`@Json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';` - Should return empty

`@Json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[1,2,3]';` - Should return rows with Id In (1,2,3)

**I can't use temp tables and CTE, because I need to filter the data in a subquery**

I would appreciate any help in determining the optimal and efficient way to filter the rows of table A based on the variable JSON array.

**I resolve my problem with**

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(max) = null

SELECT  *
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@Json) WITH(id INT '$') J ON a.id = J.id
WHERE @Json is null or J.Id is not null
```

I want to ensure that this is the optimal approach. Are there any other methods for filtering the rows of table A considering the specified requirements?

Comment: "I can't use temp tables and CTE, because I need to filter the data in a subquery" - not sure what you mean with subquery here, or why it would prevent you from anything. I'd probably change [] to NULL first, or use dynamic sql for the conditions. Your approach ain't bad either i guess

Answer (score 1):

`OR` conditions wreak havoc on the query optimizer. In this case, I would suggest a `UNION ALL` of two easily optimized queries, where one handles the null case, and the other handles the non-null case (zero or more IDs). The zero IDs case just naturally works.

Something like:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A a
WHERE @Json IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENJSON(@Json) WITH(id INT '$') J
JOIN A a ON a.id = J.id
WHERE @Json IS NOT NULL
```

If your select list is actually a complex list (not `a.*`) or if you have additional joins, you can wrap the above as a subquery and define your select list and joins at the outer level.

```
SELECT a.This, a.That, a.TheOtherThing
FROM (
   ... union query here ...
) a
JOIN ...
```